# Не удается подключиться к тестовой спотовой сети с помощью python binance

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, бот, key

Я использую python binance для своего торгового бота, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, как подключение бота к тестовой сети.
Он выдает ошибку типа: "APIError(code=-2008): Недопустимый идентификатор api-key".
Api Key и Api Secret в порядке. Я попытался установить соединение с тестовой сетью спот binance с помощью "testnet: bool = True"
и использовал accountType, но ничего не сработало
Код:
Code: https://github.com/ApelsinYT/RSI-Trade-Bot

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я хочу подключить бота к binance спот testnet, но у меня не получается. Выдаёт ошибку: APIError(code=-2008): Недопустимый идентификатор api-key, но с api всё впорядке. Я его сгенерировал на сайте https://testnet.binance.vision/ . Я пробовал testnet: bool = True, но ничего не получалось